# Download iPhoto for Yosemite?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, photos.app

How can I download the last iPhoto version for Yosemite?

Looks like any links are invalid now that Photos is out.

And upgrading a pre-Yosemite version does not work. There is an update button but it does not do anything but disable itself when clicked.

Comment: You need to understand that "does not work" has no value here, try to explain why...

Comment: You are kidding me, @Kyslik, are you? I wrote directly after that "does not work" why it does not work. Is the phrase `does not work` that scary here? So again: There is an update button but it does not do anything but disable itself when clicked.

Comment: No I'm not kidding anyone, I am looking for logs, some kind of error identifier, "disable itself...." does not help anyone. Whatever explanation you gave us is not helping at all. Of course we all are looking for "why".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you purchased the iPhoto? If yes, you should see it in App Store > Purchases tab.

EDIT: The problem was: Clicking on "Update" button didn't update application.

Solution: Delete and redownload application.

Comment: Yes, it was a purchase (or to be exact, it was an auto-purchase bundled with the Mac), and it is visible under _Purchases_, and there is an update button, but clicking it does not download any update (you can see using Activity Monitor, network), and the button is just disabled. No error is shown either.

Comment: Try to backup application to external drive, delete from Launchpad and try to redownload. This may fix issue for you. I am able to download on Yosemite.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this works. Downloading now, then we'll see if it's the right version. Weird.

Comment: You're welcome! App Store does detect actual version of OS X, so it will show if it wouldn't be compatible. I'm not sure in unpublished or removed applications. App Store also acts weird sometimes.

Answer (score -2):

Downloading from "Purchases" works for me (July 2015)